# SSL apache2 settings no pointing to rails4 app

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, deployment

My apache config `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` is:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.bollymovi.es
DocumentRoot /home/fizzy/bollyflix/production/current/public
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /home/app/certs/bollymovi.es.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/app/certs/bollymovi.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /home/app/certs/gd_bundle-g2.crt
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1 +SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:+SHA1:+MD5:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
</VirtualHost>
```

It is redirecting to `https` but not showing me:

```
This webpage is not available
```

I checked my rails app production log, nothing is there, no request came there.

To check it [click here](http://www.bollymovi.es)

Comment: Did you open the firewall port 443? Did you _restart_ Apache? Did you pay CloudFlare?

Comment: No i didn't paid to CloudFare. I don't know about that as i am doing it first time. I generated `Certificate Request` and paste it on `Godaddy` then i get `bollymovi.es.crt` and `gd_bundle-g2.crt` files. I copied both on server and using in my `apache.conf` file. These are the steps i followed.

Answer (score 1):

Your site is hosted behind CloudFlare. Using SSL on CloudFlare requires [a paid CloudFlare account](https://support.cloudflare.com/entries/23357871-My-SSL-isn-t-working-Why-not-). Contact CloudFlare to make the necessary arrangements.

Comment: I removed my site from CloudFare and pointing it to my server directly  from Godaddy. Now what should i do?